# Using Data Frame name as Column Name

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm appending multiple data frames into a larger dataframe using rbind. I would like to add the name of the data frame as a new column, "name".

```
n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc") 
d1 = data.frame(n, s)     

n = c(2, 3, 5) 
s = c("ax", "bx", "cx") 
d2 = data.frame(n, s)

rbind(d1, d2)
```

I'd like to see a new column with "d1" and "d2" as variables. I'm doing it on lots of datasets so eventhough this example is simple the final prdoct will save me a bunch of time. Thx

Comment: `do.call(rbind, mget(c("d1", "d2")))` gets you close. I'm pretty sure this question is a duplicate though.

Comment: `list(d1 = d1, d2 = d2)`

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction @anando. The answers there work well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're looking for the good ole' `deparse(substitute())` trick here. Below i've modified your code to add an additional column to each `data.frame` that consists of just the name of the `data.frame` itself.

```
n = c(2, 3, 5)
s = c("aa", "bb", "cc")
d1 = data.frame(n, s)
d1$name <- deparse(substitute(d1))

n = c(2, 3, 5)
s = c("ax", "bx", "cx")
d2 = data.frame(n, s)
d2$name <- deparse(substitute(d2))

d3 <- rbind(d1, d2)
```

When you merge them together the resulting `data.frame` looks like

```
!> d3
   n  s name
 1 2 aa   d1
 2 3 bb   d1
 3 5 cc   d1
 4 2 ax   d2
 5 3 bx   d2
 6 5 cx   d2
```

Comment: `rep_len(ls(pattern = "d(1|2)"),2*nrow(d1))` also, for the names